# Match tag in placement.info doesn't work in my case

Tags: orchardcms-1.10

I use Orchard CMS 1.10.1. I have a content type named "Animal" and I have a content Item named "Gold fish". This content item has a MediaLibraryPicker Field.
this field has a "Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary" that shows the create date. what I need is to not display this Create Date.

In Placement.info file of my current theme I added this Code to achieve my goal

```
<Match ContentType="Animal">
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
</Match>
```

This doesn't work but when I put the Place tag without Match tag it works.

My question is what is wrong with my match tag? what is the problem?

ps: ContentType Animal is correct and I also used nested Match tags for Display type Detail and summery also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the MediaLibraryPickerField renders another Meta part, specific for the image.

Try this in your placement.info:

```
<Match ContentType="Animal">
    <Place Parts_Image_Metadata="-" />
</Match>
```